# SVG TextPath Text shows upside-down

Tags: javascript, svg

Below is the SVG Code that shows the text on the path upside down. Please help show how to display it correctly upside.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path id="link1" d="M 500,140 C 200,140 200,190 500,190" stroke-width="20" fill="transparent" stroke="red"></path>
    <text class="text_path">
        <textPath xlink:href="#link1" startOffset="10">
            <tspan dy="5">Some Text</tspan><tspan class="dir_arrow">→</tspan>
        </textPath>
    </text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upside-down text in SVG textpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50909092/upside-down-text-in-svg-textpath)

Comment: Is the text intended to appear at the same place, i.e on the top of the curve? If so, then the text isn't upside-down, it's rotated by 180°. Editing the image in a free program like Inkscape eliminates much of the guesswork in these matters. ;)

Comment: This is something I render using JS. The duplicate relates to some other issue. Any way i can rotate the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're drawing the curve from bottom to top, the text is following the orientation of the drawing curve and is "upside down".

If you want the text the other way, then you need to draw the curve from top to bottom so the direction of the drawing matches the orientation of the text you want.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="600px" height="600px">
    <g>
        <path id="link1" d="M 500,190 C  200,190 200,140 500,140" stroke-width="20" fill="transparent" stroke="red"></path>
        <text class="text_path">
            <textPath xlink:href="#link1" startOffset="370">
                <tspan dy="5" class="dir_arrow">←</tspan><tspan>Some Text</tspan>
            </textPath>
        </text>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: If I make the path in a vector software, how do I make sure that I'm drawing it from top to bottom?

Comment: It depends on the software package. If there is only one way to draw an arc and the built-in default is bottom to top, then you'll need to use the "flip vertically" function (or the equivalent in your package) to get the curve the right way up.